# very basic angular2 form not getting validated

Tags: html, angular

I have a very basic form consisting of a input field and a button.  I am trying to use angular2 validators to show an error message when anything other than numbers are entered into the input field and also to disable the submit button when the input field is invalid or empty.  For some reason the error message shows regardless of what gets entered...  Any idea what i'm doing wrong?

my code:

app.component.html:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-push-4">
<form [formGroup]="barcodeForm"  role="form" (ngSubmit)="submitBarcode(barcode)" >
    <div class="form-group">        
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="barcode" placeholder="Enter Barcode" [formControl]="barcodeForm.controls['barcode']" [(ngModel)]="barcode" name="barcode" #focusInput>
        <div [hidden]="barcode.valid || barcode.pristine" class="alert alert-danger">A barcode can only consist of numbers (0-9)...</div>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-submit btn-block" [disabled]="!(barcode.valid) || barcode.pristine">Submit</button>
</form>

</div>
</div>
```

part of app.component.ts:

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { RestService } from "./services/rest.service";
import { ProductModel } from "./models/product.model";


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
@ViewChild('focusInput') focusInput: ElementRef;
barcode: string;
barcodeForm: FormGroup;
product: ProductModel;

    constructor(fb: FormBuilder, private restService: RestService){
        this.barcodeForm = fb.group({
            'barcode':['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern("[0-9]+")]]
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In angular2 there are two types of forms: template driven and model driven.

- Model driven is defining the form's structure in code and binding inputs to its controls (via `formControl` and `formGroup`). 
  And template driven is using `ngModel` and defining validators on the template.

I can see most of your code is targeted for model driven which in my opinion is better anyway, but you still have `ngModel` on your input, do you need it for something?
I dont see you using it anywhere other than `barcode.valid` which shouldn't work since `barcode` is merely a string. You want to bind the `disabled` property to `barcodeForms.controls['barcode'].valid` instead and then remove the use of `ngModel`. It might conflict with `formControl` since both of them initialize a `FormControl` instance for that element.

Comment: How could I get the barcode field's value without the ngModel?  I don't have a barcode model as it's just a barcode:string...

Comment: Use the following: `(ngSubmit)="submitBarcode(barcodeForm.value.barcode)"`

Comment: Thanks  a lot @Amit Dahan